# jquery does not focus back on the element

Tags: jquery, css, focus

I have the following code to check if the users' text does not contain the two forbidden characters and it does go the way I want. the problem is that for the texts containing the forbidden characters, I want to focus on the input after the alert goes off. yet the css style is applied to the input.

What point am I missing in this piece of code?

```
$(".option, .fixed").blur(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    if(str.indexOf("|") >= 0 || str.indexOf(":") >= 0) {
        alert("The informatin you provided contains illegal characters( | : )");    
    }
    $(this).css('border','1px solid pink').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is executed while the `blur` event is bubbling up the DOM tree, before it has been completely resolved. The element will loose its focus only when the event hits the bottom of the stack and is processed by the browser.

If you call `.focus()` while inside that function, the `focus` action will be executed, then the `blur` action will be resumed, and the original input will ultimately loose its focus.

You need to have the `focus`  trigger after the `blur` has been processed by the browser.

You can use `setTimeout` :

```
$(".option, .fixed").blur(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    if(str.indexOf("|") >= 0 || str.indexOf(":") >= 0) {
        alert("The informatin you provided contains illegal characters( | : )");    
    }
    $(this).css('border','1px solid pink');

    var that = this;
    setTimeout( function(){ $(that).focus() }, 0 );
});
```

---

However, you should be aware of the problems linked to this pattern : giving `focus` to a node can trigger `blur` on another one, and lead to a strange/broken gui behavior.

Here is an example ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/syXT3/1/)) :

- click on the first input, then outside it : you will see the desired behavior,
- click on the first input, then on the second : you will have an infinite `blur`/`focus` loop, and an unusable gui.

The simplest way to avoid this is to highlight the field, display the error message, and let the focus be.

Comment: Could you please explain more about how I place this code? cause I tried this in a couple of different ways and could not get any result!

Comment: Replace `$(this).css('border','1px solid pink').focus();` by the lines of code @LeGEC mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

with a little chang to LeGEC's solution suitable to my case:

```
$(".option, .fixed").blur(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    if(str.indexOf("|") >= 0 || str.indexOf(":") >= 0) {
        alert("The informatin you provided contains illegal characters( | : )");
        $(this).css('border','1px solid pink');
        var that = this;
        setTimeout( function(){ that.focus() }, 0 );
    }else{
        $(this).css('border','1px solid #ccc');
    }
});
```